Magento 2 - Logout not possible, because controller request is cached on client
I am unable to logout on one of my projects.

The customer/account/logout/ controller request, is getting cached.
The image showing that the Cache-Control Header is set to max-age=86400, public, s-maxage=86400 which leads to the request being cached on disk and not called anymore. If I put a xdebug breakpoint inside the controller, then it is not triggered.
I am using redis and the built in magento 2 cache.
I know how I can fix this with a plugin and I already have such a solution, but since I don't have this problem on another machine with the same project and also using the same caching procedure, it shows that it must be a configuration problem.
I tried it on another machine where redis is not setup and configured to be used, and I have the same problem. So I can exclude that redis is the problem.

Logout should be POST only not GET, If you see default Magento 2 logout, it is POST only..So it will never be cached!

You are right, but on the other hand, it also works with GET on the other machine. So my question remains, why is it different?

may be other machine don't have additional cache system!

No, it uses the exact same cache system. It is basically just a clone.

seems there is something else in there that is setting that?

is there varnish setup
is there some other caching involved?

I would first try to identify all the components that interfere between browser and server.
Second - you can add a random unique string at the end (logout + date(YmdHis) ) - to make the url unique (not really recommended - but it can be a quick fix until you figure out what is going on)

No, there is only the magento 2 built in cache and redis (only used for page cache), but the problem also exist without redis. @Pawan gave me a good hint. It uses a GET request instead of POST, this might be the reason.

But on the other hand, it also works with GET on the other machine. So my question remains, why is it different?
